# How do I take a shot without the volume display on screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, screenshots

How do I take a screenshot on my Samsung Galaxy 10.1 without the volume display showing on screen?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're on TouchWiz and are trying to take a screenshot by using Vol - and Power.

On TouchWiz it's Home + Power.

Answer (score 0):

there are many free app on the Play Store that can acquire a screenshot without pressing any physical button on your phone. Please take a look there: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.screenshoteasy.  Hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I have battled this issue ever since they pushed Android version 4.2.2. On my Galaxy Tab model GT-P5113 the <kbd>power</kbd> + <kbd>volume down</kbd> would work only about once every 10-20 attempts. Since the new build was pushed last week I checked it again. Now the screen shot does not work at all.

But I gave up long ago and came up with a solution. I use my Samsung Victory telephone to take a picture of the tablet and send that to the tablet to by whatever share method is handy.

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>Vol -</kbd> plus <kbd>Power</kbd> button at the same time.

Comment: I guess that's what the OP tried, as indicated by "without the volume display showing on screen". Either timing is a bit tricky here (which is the case for some devices), or Samsung is using a [different hotkey-combination](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/69825/16575) on its devices. Are you sure your hint applies to the Galaxy 10.1?